# SQL Server 2008 timeout on insert

Tags: sql-server

I have an issue with insert time out. My table has a size of 12 gb and 12 million rows.

Sometimes I get timeout on insert. I have an insert query every 5 sec on average.

I suspect that I have lock escalations on the table when end user performs a select.

What is the best practice to avoid insert time out on large tables?

Is to create two tables one insert second for select ? replication ? SQL AVAILABILITY Groups ? table partitioning ? any other options?

(soon  we are going to upgrade to SQL Server 2016)

regards,
Pavel.

Answer (score 1):

I would enable **Read-Committed Snapshot Isolation**, which does row versioning under the covers by making use of tempdb. Readers will not block writers, which is what you're looking for in this scenario.

This is a per-database level setting, which doesn't require a reboot. However, you must have tempdb configured correctly (appropriate fixed-size file growth, sufficient data files, etc.).

```
ALTER DATABASE MyDatabase SET READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT ON;
GO
```

*(Read more here: [Choosing Row Versioning-based Isolation Levels](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188277.aspx).)*

Answer (score 0):

Update statements can take timeouts for thousand of reasons. Thus, you should check the wait type of inserts and then try to narrow the problem to find the bottleneck.

It can be resulted from blocking as you mentioned and snapshot isolation could solved it as Randolph suggests. However, you can also add (nolock) hint to your long-running select queries. It's always better to offload report queries to a secondary server if you can.

CPU or I\O could be the reason if the system resources are not enough for the instance.

I would also suggest you to check VLF Counts of the db that your insert queries taking long.

Here is the query to check vlf count, It shouldn't be more than 500.

```
--variables to hold each 'iteration'  
declare @query varchar(100)  
declare @dbname sysname  
declare @vlfs int  

--table variable used to 'loop' over databases  
declare @databases table (dbname sysname)  
insert into @databases  
--only choose online databases  
select name from sys.databases where state = 0  

--table variable to hold results  
declare @vlfcounts table  
    (dbname sysname,  
    vlfcount int)  



--table variable to capture DBCC loginfo output  
--changes in the output of DBCC loginfo from SQL2012 mean we have to determine the version 

declare @MajorVersion tinyint  
set @MajorVersion = LEFT(CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar(max)),CHARINDEX('.',CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS nvarchar(max)))-1) 

if @MajorVersion < 11 -- pre-SQL2012 
begin 
    declare @dbccloginfo table  
    (  
        fileid tinyint,  
        file_size bigint,  
        start_offset bigint,  
        fseqno int,  
        [status] tinyint,  
        parity tinyint,  
        create_lsn numeric(25,0)  
    )  

    while exists(select top 1 dbname from @databases)  
    begin  

        set @dbname = (select top 1 dbname from @databases)  
        set @query = 'dbcc loginfo (' + '''' + @dbname + ''') '  

        insert into @dbccloginfo  
        exec (@query)  

        set @vlfs = @@rowcount  

        insert @vlfcounts  
        values(@dbname, @vlfs)  

        delete from @databases where dbname = @dbname  

    end 
end 
else 
begin 
    declare @dbccloginfo2012 table  
    (  
        RecoveryUnitId int, 
        fileid tinyint,  
        file_size bigint,  
        start_offset bigint,  
        fseqno int,  
        [status] tinyint,  
        parity tinyint,  
        create_lsn numeric(25,0)  
    )  

    while exists(select top 1 dbname from @databases)  
    begin  

        set @dbname = (select top 1 dbname from @databases)  
        set @query = 'dbcc loginfo (' + '''' + @dbname + ''') '  

        insert into @dbccloginfo2012  
        exec (@query)  

        set @vlfs = @@rowcount  

        insert @vlfcounts  
        values(@dbname, @vlfs)  

        delete from @databases where dbname = @dbname  

    end --while 
end 

--output the full list  
select @@SERVERNAME,dbname, vlfcount  
from @vlfcounts  
order by vlfcount desc
```